# Single app - drastically different views/usage - how?

Tags: angularjs

I have a large app with a structure and UI that has been designed to meet the original requirements.

I am now faced with a situation where I have to make an alternative read-only "view" of certain parts of the app for embedding in an iframe (I have no say in this, this is how it has to be).

I'll be referring to these two ways of viewing the app at the "display context".

I am struggling with visualising how to achive this, I can see two solutions both of which have distinct disadvantages:

- Have lots of `ng-if` directives attached to template elements, the `ng-if` would be bound to the current display context of the app and show/hide elements depending on how it was being used. Even if these were one-time bindings, it would potentially turn the templates into an unreadable mess of nested `ng-if`s everywhere
- Create entirely separate templates for the two different display contexts. While much cleaner than the first option, it would mean a lot of duplication and maintaining two templates per view whereas previously it would be one.

I should add that the nature of the views is very `ng-repeat` heavy, a list of data containing categories, each category contains items, each item contains a multitude of data, at each level data may need to be hidden/displayed/manipulated for display depending on the display context. I have made heavy use of directives and components to break things up into logical chunks, however these directives and components are still very much geared towards the original use, rather than the newly required one.

I have also considered creating an entirely new app for this, however I'm not sure this would bring any benefits as I'd be using controllers and injecting services containing tons of stuff that would be never used, I'd also be increasing my duplication problem.

Does anyone have any feeling, suggestions on a good way forward for this as at the moment I'm feeling anything is going to be horrible.

Many thanks

Comment: IMO, subtemplating instead of high complexity templates. Sometimes redudance is much more comfortable than complexity.